# Magento 2 : Error when try to set image for product and save

Tags: magento2, product, php, image

When i'm trying to set image for the product

```
$configurable->setMediaGallery(array('images'=>array (), 'values'=>array ()));
$path = $this->helper->uploadImage($data->main_image);
if ($path && file_exists($path)) {
    $configurable->addImageToMediaGallery($path, array('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail'), true, false);
}
```

and then when save it i'm getting an error

> Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\FileSystemException): The file "... pub/media/tmp/catalog/product/8/1/81cz5-izU0L.jpg" doesn't exist or not a file

Looks like some permission issue but i've checked all directories have all needed access.
Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Comment: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/install/legacy-file-system-perms.html please check

Comment: there are just recommendations for permissions. But for tests I've made all dirs under pub/media 777. And still have same error.

Comment: i will check more on this

Answer (score 1):

The file path should be relative to media folder. Below I'll try to explain why.

So **addImageToMediaGallery** calls **Model\Product\Gallery\Processor.php::addImage**

```
 $file = $this->mediaDirectory->getRelativePath($file);
 if (!$this->mediaDirectory->isFile($file)) {
      throw new LocalizedException(__('The image does not exist.'));
 }
```

You can do a debug of the **$file**, and then keep digging which will eventually bring you to **Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\Read**

Particularly this *line 219*: **$this->driver->getAbsolutePath($this->path, $path)**

Now, if your path was "**/fullpath/pub/media/../file.jpg**" which you passed to **addImageToMediaGallery**, then by debugging the result of **getAbsolutePath** call, you will get something like this:

> /fullpath/pub/media/fullpath/pub/media/../file.jpg

So your path is prefixed with the full server path to your media folder and that's make it invalid and therefore exception 'The image does not exist.' is thrown.

Hope it makes it more clear now.

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same error when I was trying to save the additional images as part of the main import. So I set the main as part of the first import and set the additional images after that using the following code. That works for me.

```
 $imgs = explode('|',$prodData[10]);

        if(sizeof($imgs) > 1) {

            $product = $_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($newProdId);
            $productRepository = $_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface');
            $productRepository->save($product);

            for ( $i=1; $i<sizeof($imgs); $i++ ) {

                echo 'Add Images :' . $prdbasepath.basename(trim($imgs[$i])) . PHP_EOL;
                $image_directory = $prdbasepath.'data'.DS.basename(trim($imgs[$i]));


                if (file_exists($image_directory) && getimagesize($image_directory)) {

                    echo 'File exists'.PHP_EOL;
                    $product->addImageToMediaGallery($image_directory, array('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail'), false, false);
                    $product->save();

                }
            }

        }
```